# unkown error syntax error unexpected token export while check angular version in ubuntu

Tags: node.js, angular, ubuntu, npm, version

After installing node.js and angular i wanted to check version of my angular.

[image: r]

Each time I am getting this error

```
unkown error syntax error unexpected token export
```

so what is the  right way to check version of angular in ubuntu?

Comment: Did you try to resinstall the ng-cli?

Comment: @yazantahhan yes

Comment: Can you try to downgrade the node version to 12 and try again?

Comment: @yazantahhan sorry no. i need that latest version

Comment: @yazantahhan later maybe

Comment: You can use a tool like [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) or  [n](https://github.com/tj/n) to install multiple versions and quickly switch between them